# $G$ finite centerless group, $H,K\le G$ such that $HK(=KH)=G$ and $H\cap K=\{1\}$. Does it follow that either $H\unlhd G$ or $K\unlhd G$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups

Let $G$ be a finite centerless group and $H,K\le G$ such that $HK(=KH)=G$ and $H\cap K=\{1\}$. Does it follow that *either* $H\unlhd G$ *or $K\unlhd G$*? Not sure that the centerless condition is relevant for my question, but I mention it as this is the case I'm interested in. As for the context, this popped up while trying to prove without Sylow's theorems that a group of order $p^\alpha q$ ($p,q$ distinct primes) is not simple, which clearly amounts to proving that for the centerless case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, $G=A_5$, $H=A_4$, $K=C_5$.

There are lots more examples of factorizations of simple groups.

Answer (score 2):

And this seems to be a minimal counterexample:
$G=S_4$, $H=S_3$, $K=\langle(1234)\rangle$.

**Addendum.**

No, this is not a minimal counterexample. There is a counterexample of the order of $16$:
$$
G=\langle a,b,c\mid a^4=b^2=c^2=1,ab=ba,bc=ca^2\rangle,\ H=\langle a\rangle,\ K=\langle b,ca^2\rangle. 
$$
We have $G\equiv(\langle a\rangle\times\langle b\rangle)\rtimes\langle c\rangle$ and $|H|=|K|=4$ and $H\cap K=\{1\}$.

But this example is more complicated as we can see and this group has a center.

Comment: Surely the example of order $16$ is not centerless...

Comment: Yes that's true, thank you.